# LINQ Methods are Extension Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I want to understand LINQ and did some research on the matter and discovered that `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` have LINQ methods. However when I look at the documentation of these types I don't see any LINQ methods.

Are the LINQ methods extension methods that are inserted in `IEnumerable/IQueryable` types at runtime and if so why?

Comment: This seems like a question that's going to get opinionated answers.  I think you are about to start a flame war.

Comment: Extension methods aren't inserted at runtime.

Comment: Read [Following the pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) by Eric Lippert. Explains the reasons.

Comment: The LINQ methods are extension methods, yes, but they are not "inserted at runtime" into anything. An extension method is a *compile time* concept, not a *runtime* concept. An extension method is just a convenient syntax for writing a static method call; it has no effect on the type system at runtime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding the methods on IEnumerable would mean that all types that derive from IEnumerable would have to implement them themselves. Now with extensions methods we can sort of add implementations to interfaces.

An other side effect would be that code written in .NET 2.0 would still compile with 3.0 when Linq was introduced. Otherwise if you had implemented IEnumerable somewhere in your project you would now have to implement all the new methods in the interface as well.

The LINQ methods for Linq To Objects are defined on the [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class.

Moreover, LINQ searches for methods that are declared using a specific syntax and is not interface or class based. You might find the [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series of Jon Skeet interesting.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) link on extension methods.

Comment: thats classy explaination. And for sure, jons articles are top notch!